# Should I be able to create supervised user with blank name in CrOS and crash is seen in linux on importing that blank supervised user

Tags: android, jquery, linux, google-chrome

Should I be able to create supervised user with blank name in CrOS

Crash is seen in linux on importing that blank supervised user

Version: 54.0.2806.0/8639.0.0

OS: Chrome os

What steps will reproduce the problem?
In CrOS:
(1) Sign in to user and sign out >> Now click on 3 dot menu to add supervised user 
(2) Now on create supervised user page >> Enter password and confirm password[Do not enter any name] 
(3) Now click continuously on camera icon on that page so that supervised user is automatically created.
Now sign in to User in Linux/Windows:
(1) Click on Add Person button in chrome://settings >> Now on that overlay Clear name field and check "Control and view ..." checkbox
(2) Click on import link,Select Supervised user with blank name >> Click ok,import button and observe.

I can't delete the blank supervised user from Supervised Users Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug and is currently untriaged in chromium

[Bug Report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=632275&q=os%3Dchrome&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)